# Add and remove input elements with Bootstrap Touchspin

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use bootstrap touchspin to dynamically create a series of input areas, which would later be used to create a word array, but I had some problems with the creation of the elements. I can create elements, but the issue is removing them, I'm trying to get this to work

```
    <script>
    var limit = 40;
    var counter= 0;
        $("input[name='cant']").TouchSpin({
            min: 0,
        }).on('change', function (){ 
            var number = $(this).val();

            if ((number) >= limit)  {
                alert("Word limit reached");
                number=limit;
                }
                if(number >= counter){
                    for(i=counter;i<number;i++) {
                    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
                    newdiv.innerHTML = "<br><input type='text' id='word"+i+"'>";
                    document.getElementById("ingresar").appendChild(newdiv);
                    counter++;
                    }else{
                        for(i=counter;i>number;i--){
                            document.getElementById("word"+i).remove();
                            counter--;
                        }
                    }
                }

        ;});
    </script>
```

Is there something I'm missing? my guess is that playing with the element IDs is messing my code up. Is there another more efficient way of doing it?

Comment: Well, `domNode.remove()` is somewhat supported in the latest browsers, but you're probably trying to use the jQuery method, in which case you'd need a jQuery object, so `$('#word' + i).remove()`. Also, you're not targeting the DIV you inserted, but the input inside it ?

Comment: Perfect, that was it, I used: $('#word' + i).parent().remove() and fixed a few issues with my sintaxis and it's now working perfectly, thank you for your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a few errors in sintaxis (and logic): Fixed with $('#word' + i).parent().remove()

```
    if(number >= counter){
                    for(i=counter;i<number;i++) {
                    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
                    newdiv.innerHTML = "<br><input type='text' id='word"+i+"'>";
                    document.getElementById("ingresar").appendChild(newdiv);
                    }
                    counter=number;
                }else{
                    for(i=counter;i>number-1;i--){
                        $('#word' + i).parent().remove()
                        }
                        counter=number;
                    }
```